# Trying to split iPhone & iPad sizes for specific part of game

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

in my game I have a bingo board, using various defines, the ones relating to this question are;

```
#define BTNNUMBER_SX     43// iPad should be 43
#define BTNNUMBER_SY     105 // iPad should be 85
#define BTNNUMBER_DX     47 // iPad should be 27
#define BTNNUMBER_DY     25 // iPad should be 15
```

As it currently is, they work fine on iPhone, however the spacing is not correct on the iPad, and I figured the differences and wrote them next to the defines, however, I am trying to figure out how I can split them to show one set of values for iPhone, and the other for iPad?

Being used here;

```
    for (int c = 0; c < _cardNumber; c++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if ( i == 2 && j == 2 ) {
                    float x = BTNNUMBER_SX + i * (BTNNUMBER_W + BTNNUMBER_DX);
                    float y = BTNNUMBER_SY + j * (BTNNUMBER_H + BTNNUMBER_DY);
                    float w = BTNNUMBER_W;
                    float h = BTNNUMBER_H;
                    x *= padScale;
                    y *= padScale;
                    w *= padScale;
                    h *= padScale;
                    x += _ivBingoPad[c].frame.origin.x;
                    y += _ivBingoPad[c].frame.origin.y;

                    _btnBingo[c] = [[BingoButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
                    [_btnBingo[c] setTitle: @"" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
                    [_btnBingo[c] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bingo_free_button"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
                    [_btnBingo[c] addTarget: self action:@selector( success ) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [self.view addSubview: _btnBingo[c]];
#ifdef DEVELOPMENT
                    _btnBingo[c].enabled = YES;
#else
                    _btnBingo[c].enabled = NO;
#endif
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And also being used here;

```
if ([MainViewController isPad] == NO) {
        if (_blUpperScreen) {
            if (_cardNumber > 2)
                _btnBingo[2].hidden = true;
            if (_cardNumber == 4)
                _btnBingo[3].hidden = true;
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < _cardNumber; c++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                float x = BTNNUMBER_SX + i * (BTNNUMBER_W + BTNNUMBER_DX);
                float y = BTNNUMBER_SY + j * (BTNNUMBER_H + BTNNUMBER_DY);
                float w = BTNNUMBER_W;
                float h = BTNNUMBER_H;
                x *= padScale;
                y *= padScale;
                w *= padScale;
                h *= padScale;
                x += _ivBingoPad[c].frame.origin.x;
                y += _ivBingoPad[c].frame.origin.y;

                if ( i == 2 && j == 2 ) {
                }
                else {
                    _btnNumberArr[i][j][c] = [[NumberButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
                    _btnNumberArr[i][j][c].statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bingocard_select"];
                    _btnNumberArr[i][j][c].font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 40*padScale];
                    [_btnNumberArr[i][j][c] setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
                    [self.view addSubview: _btnNumberArr[i][j][c]];
                    [_btnNumberArr[i][j][c] addTarget: _btnNumberArr[i][j][c] action:@selector(onClick) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [_btnNumberArr[i][j][c] setParam:_cardRep[c] :_globals :j :i :_bingoChecker :_btnBingo[c]];
                    if ([BingoCheckerPostageStamp hasPatternXY:_cardRep[c]:j:i] && profile.gameRoom.intValue == GAME_ROOM_POSTAGESTAMP) {
                        [_btnNumberArr[i][j][c] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bingocard_pattern_mark"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an idea :)

```html
#define IPAD  UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

#define EXAMPLE (IPAD ? 24 : 35) // IPAD 24, Otherwise 35
```

Comment: Works great thank you! Although I needed to adfd the IPAD ? inside ( bracket )